# Is there any way to stop my C# application trying to load a .resources file that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, caliburn.micro

I am writing a Caliburn.Micro application in which I am loading a View from an assembly.
The `Assembly.Load` call runs fine but then when the Activator attempts to create the view, my `AssemblyResolve` kicks in and then fails:

```
ERROR - AssemblyResolve could not find StandardMenu.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
```

In the project settings of the assembly, I have "Icon and manifest" enabled, rather than "Resource file".

There is no StandardMenu.resources. It doesn't exist, so why is it trying to be loaded?

Comment: Don't fail AssemblyResolve requests for assemblies that you don't know about or cannot find.  Return null.

Comment: This is not the solution but certainly a good point. I was throwing an exception - it's much cleaner without.